# How to print specific data from JSON file lists in a line break layout?

Tags: python, json, database, list, dictionary

## Take this example:

```
    "something": {
        "random": 0,
        "bag": {
            "papers": 0,
            "pencils": 0
        },
        "PAINT": {
            "COLORS": [
                "A WHITE",
                "B MAPLE",
                "B LOTUS",
                "A OLIVE"
            ],
            "CANS": [
                "SOMETHING"
            ] 
    }
```

Ignore everything and focus on the COLORS list in the PAINT dictionary... I want to print all colors that have the color A before them, as a code. In other words I want to print "A WHITE"  and "A OLIVE". Here's what happens when I do this:

```
with open("somethings.json", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

print(data["something"]["PAINT"]["COLORS"])
```

This is the output:

```
["A WHITE", "B MAPLE", "B LOTUS", "A OLIVE"]
```

but like I said, I do not want that... I want only A colors to be printed...
I also do not want THIS:

```
["A WHITE", "A OLIVE"]
```

the output that I really want (which is quite specific) is this:

```
OLIVE
WHITE
```

With line breaks (optional: AND in alphabetical order) that is the output that I want. So how can I print this output? is it possible without using any 'for' loops? This is a very specific question, would appreciate some help. Thanks -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```py
with open("somethings.json", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

a_colors = [color for color in data["something"]["PAINT"]["COLORS"] if color.startswith("A ")]
colors = [a_color.replace("A ", "") for a_color in a_colors]

print(colors)
```

#### How it works

1. Opens and loads the JSON data.
2. Uses a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to filter only entries that start with `"A "`.
   The `.startswith()` method of a string returns a boolean value, `True` if the first few characters of the string are, in fact, the characters passed as an argument, and `False` otherwise.
3. Uses another list comprehension to get the string without the `"A "` for each string in the list created in step 2.
   Replaces the `"A "` with an empty string, which is a hacky way of deleting part of a string using the `.replace()` method.

#### It can be done without list comprehensions using a for loop as well

See code below:

```py
with open("somethings.json", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

a_colors = []
for color in data["something"]["PAINT"]["COLORS"]:
    if color.startswith("A "):
        color_without_a = color.replace("A ", "")
        a_colors.append(color_without_a)

print(a_colors)
```

This solution uses a for loop rather than a list comprehension but is otherwise the same. (If you are confused, see below for a solution which is an exact replica of the list comprehension one but implemented with for loops).

If you are interested, here is a lengthier solution more similar to the list comprehension one, using for loops:

```py
with open("somethings.json", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

a_colors = []

for color in data["something"]["PAINT"]["COLORS"]:
    if color.startswith("A "):
        a_colors.append(color)

colors = []

for a_color in a_colors:
    colors.append(a_color.replace("A ", ""))
    
print(colors)
```

To sort alphabetically, use the `sorted()` function, like this for the list comprehension solution and the second for loop solution:

```py
sorted_list = sorted(colors)
print(sorted_list)
```

For the first for loop solution:

```py
sorted_list = sorted(a_colors)
print(sorted_list)
```

#### Recommended reading

- [Python Data Structures documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [Examples of list comprehensions for practice](https://towardsdatascience.com/11-examples-to-master-python-list-comprehensions-33c681b56212?gi=a1310f4ad564)
- [Beginner's list comprehension tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-list-comprehensions/)
- [Filtering lists in Python](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-filter-list/)

#### Other helpful resources

- [List slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)
- [Sorting Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

I *strongly* recommend watching this video as well:

- [Python Tutorial for Beginners 7: Loops and Iterations - For/While Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iF8Xb7Z3wQ)

---

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't really don't use a `for`-loop, you need to iterate over all elements in your `COLORS` array.
So, what you want to do is:

1. Iterate over all elements
2. Check if the first character of each element (e.g. `A WHITE`) is the desired character (e.g. `A`)
3. either print the output directly or store it in list without the `A`  (notice the space)

So:

```py
with open("somethings.json", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

colors = data["something"]["PAINT"]["COLORS"]
best_colors = []

for color in colors:
  if color[0] == "A": # or any character you want; CASE SENSITIVE!
    best_colors.append(color[2:]) # this adds the color without the A and the space to the list

# Optionally: Sort alphabetically
sorted_colors = sorted(best_colors)
```

Additional resources to help you to understand the code better:

- [List slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)
- [Sorting Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Unix Doughnut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785823/14319439):

```
# Read JSON File
with open("file_name.json", "r") as f: 
    data = json.load(f)

# Sort the selected elements starting with A without the leading A
colors = sorted([color.replace("A ", "") for color in data["something"]["PAINT"]["COLORS"] if color.startswith("A ")])

# Print list elements separated by line break ( without for loop )
print(*colors, sep='\n')`
```